# How to pass a unique uuid to each callback?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `multer-s3-transform`, which allows me to manipulate the image coming in, before uploading it to my bucket. Here's what I have:

```
const singleImageUploadJpg = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "muh-bucket",
    acl: "public-read",
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      const fileName = uuid.v4();
      cb(null, fileName);
    },
    shouldTransform: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, true);
    },
    transforms: [
      {
        id: "original",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${uuid.v4()}.jpg`);
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      },
      {
        id: "small",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${uuid.v4()}_small.jpg`);
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
}).single("image");
```

The problem is that the uuid will always be different for the small and the original versions. How can I make `const fileName = uuid.v4()` passed down to each callback, so that they'd have the same name, with `_small` being the only difference?

Comment: Can you provide an example somehow

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. Use a single constant instead of calling `uuid.v4()` in each callback

Comment: @eugensunic There's not much else I can provide, it's a function that runs before the req.body is generate in Node

Comment: @charlietfl I have no access to that constant from one callback to another. My question is how can I make it so that I do have access? The first key is hit, then the key in `original`, then the key in `small`

Comment: have you tried `this` keyword ? @MikeK

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama throws `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that multer calls the functions provided repeatedly, which is why you don't do the obvious thing Jim Nilsson suggested. Also, sadly, you've said that the `file` you receive in the transform callback doesn't have the name you specify earlier.

Two possibilities, both assuming that either the `file` object or the `req` object you receive is the same in both callbacks:

1. Your own expando property
2. A `WeakMap`

### Expando property

You could try to piggyback it on the `file`/`req` (I use `file` below), like so (see `***` comments):

```
const singleImageUploadJpg = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "muh-bucket",
    acl: "public-read",
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      file.__uuid__ = uuid.v4();                   // ***
      cb(null, file.__uuid__);
    },
    shouldTransform: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, true);
    },
    transforms: [
      {
        id: "original",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${uuid.v4()}.jpg`);
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      },
      {
        id: "small",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${file.__uuid__}_small.jpg`);  // ***
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
}).single("image");
```

That would probably be doing something undocumented, though, which means you need to be careful to test with every "dot release" of the library you upgrade to.

### `WeakMap`:

Alternatively, you could use a `WeakMap` keyed by the `file` or `req` (I use `file` below):

```
const nameMap = new WeakMap();
const singleImageUploadJpg = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "muh-bucket",
    acl: "public-read",
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      const fileName = uuid.v4();
      nameMap.set(file, fileName);                  // ***
      cb(null, fileName);
    },
    shouldTransform: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, true);
    },
    transforms: [
      {
        id: "original",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${uuid.v4()}.jpg`);
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      },
      {
        id: "small",
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
          const fileName = nameMap.get(file); // ***
          nameMap.delete(file);               // *** (optional, presumably `file` will be released at some point, which would remove it automatically)
          cb(null, `${fileName}_small.jpg`);  // ***
        },
        transform: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(
            null,
            sharp()
              .resize()
              .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
          );
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
}).single("image");
```

Comment: Ouf, I like that one. Piggybacking off `file` was not a solution that would've come to me, I think. Great one.

Comment: @MikeK - :-) The expando is a bit of a hack (we used to need lots of hacks like that, back in the day). The `WeakMap` solution is cleaner if you can rely on `WeakMap` being supported in your environment. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a function and generate the uuid before calling multer:

```
const singleImageUploadJpg = (function()
{
    const uid = uuid.v4();
    return multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: "muh-bucket",
            acl: "public-read",
            key: function(req, file, cb) {
              const fileName = uid;
              cb(null, fileName);
            },
            shouldTransform: function(req, file, cb) {
              cb(null, true);
            },
            transforms: [
              {
                id: "original",
                key: function(req, file, cb) {
                  cb(null, `${uid}.jpg`);
                },
                transform: function(req, file, cb) {
                  cb(
                    null,
                    sharp()
                      .resize()
                      .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
                  );
                }
              },
              {
                id: "small",
                key: function(req, file, cb) {
                  cb(null, `${uid}_small.jpg`);
                },
                transform: function(req, file, cb) {
                  cb(
                    null,
                    sharp()
                      .resize()
                      .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
                  );
                }
              }
            ]
        }),
        limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
    }).single("image");
})();
```

Comment: My impression is that multer calls the functions provided repeatedly, for more than one file. If that impression is correct, this will assign the same UUID to **all** of them.

Comment: Just verified. The uuid is the same for any image uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `uuid.v4` method in your handler, which returns something different each time you do so. What you need to do is to call it once and put it in a variable

```
const singleImageUploadJpg = ( function( my_uuid )
{
    // same as before

})(  uuid.v4() );
```

And then use that variable later on

```
cb(null, `${my_uuid}.jpg`);
// ...
cb(null, `${my_uuid}_small.jpg`);
```

Comment: throws `my_uuid is not defined` in the `cb(null, `${my_uuid}.jpg`);` and the `cb(null, `${my_uuid}_small.jpg`);`

Comment: I assume you mean doing the same thing [Jim Nilsson answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737519/157247). (@MikeK - You shouldn't get that error if you do it as Jim Nilsson shows.) If so, my comment there applies: My impression is that multer calls the functions provided repeatedly, for more than one file. If that impression is correct, this will assign the same UUID to **all** of them.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737459/how-to-pass-a-unique-uuid-to-each-callback/57737595#comment101914167_57737519), my suspicion above was correct.